# Logical Maven version numbering

Tags: java, maven, version, versioning

Arg, I'm pretty sure this is a simple one but it's hurting my brain heh.
Can I please get some input from the community?

Ok..
Let's say I just released version 1.2.3.

My next release version will be 1.2.4.
So will my current working version be 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT or 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT? Is the snapshot version number the pre-release version or the post-release version? It's pre-release, 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT, correct?

My next *major* release version will be 2.0.0.
Would that mean I should make my working copy 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT? Or something like 1.9.9-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: I've often wondered the same thing. I always stuck with just making odd numbers releases and even numbers SNAPSHOTs. This helps. Thanks for asking it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1.2.4-SNAPSHOT`.

`1.2.4-snapshot` is the "in-progress" default. usually (for big projects) the numbered releases would be

- `1.2.4-m1` , `1.2.4-m2` (milestone builds)
- `1.2.4-beta1` , `1.2.4-beta2` (beta builds)
- `1.2.4-rc` (release candidate)
- `1.2.4` (or sometimes `1.2.4-final`)

and in between all those "big" releases the *-snapshots keep coming out all the time (sometimes several times a day) without getting their own version. logically the latest snapshot overrides any previous ones (though some maven repositories store a few of the prev snapshots as well)

Comment: But it's 1.2.4-SNAPSHOT not 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT? The version *number* for the SNAPSHOT is the version of the *to be released* artifact?